# Frames not disappearing when using grid_forget() - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using radio buttons to switch between frames in Tkinter, using grid_forget(), as advised in one of the other questions, related to switching between frames, but, for some reason, the old frames do not disappear.

Here are some extracts from my code:

```
def zedPanel(self):
    global toolbarZ
    self.toolbarZ = Frame(m1,bd=20, relief='flat', width=400)                                                            
    self.toolbarZ.grid()
    self.toolbarZ.place(x=1, y=850, anchor=W)

def zcgaPanel(self):
    global toolbarZcga
    self.toolbarZcga = Frame(m1,bd=20, relief='flat', width=400)
    self.toolbarZcga.grid()
    self.toolbarZcga.place(x=1, y=850, anchor=W)  

def zdraPanel(self):
    global toolbarZdra       
    self.toolbarZdra = Frame(m1,bd=20, relief='flat', width=400)
    self.toolbarZdra.grid()
    self.toolbarZdra.place(x=1, y=872, anchor=W)
```

The three functions above call frames with buttons.
The function I use to switch between them is:

```
 def selected(self):
    global toolbarZdra
    global toolbarZcga
    global toolbarZ
    global radioVar

    if radioVar.get()==1:
        self.toolbarZcga.grid_forget()
        self.toolbarZdra.grid_forget()
        self.zedPanel()

    elif radioVar.get()==2:
        self.toolbarZ.grid_forget()
        self.toolbarZdra.grid_forget()
        self.zcgaPanel()


    else:
        self.toolbarZcga.grid_forget()
        self.toolbarZ.grid_forget()
        self.zdraPanel()
```

What I am trying to do is eliminate the other two frames when the button for the third one is clicked.

The error I get is

*AttributeError: Example instance has no attribute 'toolbarZcga'*

where *Example* is the name of the class.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: The title seems to have nothing to do with the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

I think as you declare the toolbars to be global earlier, they are not attributes of the *Example*-Object. Thus `self.toolbarZcga` should be `toolbarZcga`, as global variables are not linked to your current object.

Comment: I tried changing it, by deleting 'self'  but it is still not working. The error message I get is: global name 'toolbarZcga' is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use place and grid together.  The whole point of using a geometry manager like grid is that you don't have to mess with placing widgets explicitly.  I can't say exactly what's going on, because I never use place, but I'd guess that after you do

```
self.toolbarZcga.grid()
self.toolbarZcga.place(x=1, y=850, anchor=W)
```

toolbarZcga is no longer managed by the gridder, so forgetting it has no effect. Your grid should be a table of cells arranged in rows and columns; then you just grid your widget in the appropriate cell.  There is a really good introductory explanation of how to use grid [by John Shipman](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html)

Comment: I commented out  self.toolbarZcga.place(x=1, y=850, anchor=W), but it is still not working.

Comment: But after you do grid_forget() you call zcgaPanel() again, so you do the placement all over again.  The way that event-driven programming like this works is that you start by executing some functions to set up the GUI (like zcgaPanel) and then you bind callback functions to certain widgets to respond to event like button clicks.  So you need a callback that does the gridForget and is bound to a radio button.  You're aren't using the right approach.  Start by doing something very simple.  Draw a blue square on the screen.  Make a button that will change the color to red when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Well: you use:

```
self.toolbarZcga.grid()
self.toolbarZcga.place(x=1, y=850, anchor=W)
```

And then you try to delete the grid! But you have use `place`!

```
self.toolbarZ.grid_forget()
self.toolbarZdra.grid_forget()
```

I can't work: you have to do:

```
self.toolbarZ.place_forget()
self.toolbarZdra.place_forget()
```

In fact grid, place and pack are three exclusive (for **one** widget) methods to manage positioning other widgets dependent of it!
The WM (windows manager) of tkinter let only one possibility for each widget: with a frame you chose one of them (grid, place, pack) to locate subsequent (dependent) widget. But another widget (maybe dependent of the frame) can have a different one!
But for my frame: you cannot use grid for a dependent widget and place for another because it confuse th WM!
You see??

Comment: Still not working. The problem seems to be in not declaring my variables correctly - the error I keep getting is:  global name 'toolbarZcga' is not defined.

Comment: Maybe: but it can't work declaring a `place` and deleting `grid`, No? And sure, you cannot declare `grid` and `place` at the same time!!

Comment: I see.I commented out the declaration of place and only left grid, but it doesn't seem to be working. Also - when I commented out 'place' my frame moved to another part of the window. Why can't I use both place and grid - they seem to be doing different things - 'place' seems to be fixing the position of the whole frame and 'grid' manages the position of the buttons?

Comment: @onetramp: yes! but you cannot use place and grid at the same time (into the same widget). It's one, or the other!

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. The first is what the error message is telling you: you're trying to use an attribute named `toolbarZcga`, but the object doesn't have such an attribute. You *do* have a global variable with that name. You need to be consistent and either use instance variables or global variables. Mixing them doesn't make sense. Either use `self.toolbarZcga` everywhere, or `toolbarZcga` everywhere.

The second problem is that you're using both `grid` and `place`. When you call `grid` followed by `place`, place takes control away from `grid`, meaning that `grid_forget()` will no longer do anything because `grid` doesn't control the widget. You can only use one of `grid`, `pack` or `place` for each widget, and the last one that you use is the one that controls the widget.